# How do I make a rectangle change color when a ball hits it the first and second time and then make it disappear on the third hit?

Tags: python, colors, processing, collision-detection

I am making a brick breaker game and right now the ball hits a brick (a rectangle) and it breaks on the first hit. I want it so that the first time the ball hits the brick, it changes to light red and the second to red and then on the third hit, it breaks.

```
#brick list
rectInfo = [rX, rY] 
allRectInfo = [rectInfo[:] for i in range(numRects)]
allRectInfo[0] = [45, 20, True]
allRectInfo[1] = [45, 60, True]
allRectInfo[2] = [45, 100, True]
allRectInfo[3] = [45, 140, True]
allRectInfo[4] = [195, 20, True]
allRectInfo[5] = [195, 60, True]
allRectInfo[6] = [195, 100, True]
allRectInfo[7] = [195, 140, True]
allRectInfo[8] = [345, 20, True]
allRectInfo[9] = [345, 100, True]
allRectInfo[10] = [345, 60, True]
allRectInfo[11] = [345, 140, True]
allRectInfo[12] = [495, 140, True]
allRectInfo[13] = [495, 100, True]
allRectInfo[14] = [495, 60, True]
allRectInfo[15] = [495, 20, True]
allRectInfo[16] = [645, 20, True]
allRectInfo[17] = [645, 60, True]
allRectInfo[18] = [645, 100, True]
allRectInfo[19] = [645, 140, True]

#when the ball hits the bricks
for i in range (numRects):
  if allRectInfo[i][2] == True:
    rect (allRectInfo[i][0], allRectInfo[i][1], rectW, rectH)
       if allRectInfo[i][1]-25 <= y <= allRectInfo[i][1]+74 and 
    allRectInfo[i][0]-5.5 <= x <= allRectInfo[i][0]+150:
            incry = incry * (-1)
            allRectInfo[i][2] = allRectInfo[i][2] - 1
            score = score + 1
            hits = hits + 1
```

Comment: So what is the question? You have to use a different color depending on the value of `hits ` and you have to break, when `hits ` reaches its limit of 3.

Comment: so I tried doing that but it changes the color of ALL the bricks (instead of the brick the ball hits) for a second and it goes back to white. And how do make the hits limit to 3?

Comment: The 3rd element of the tuple has to be a counter rather than a bool. See the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of an boolean attribute, the 3rd element of the `allRectInfo[i]` tuple, has to be the number of hits, initialized by 0:

```
allRectInfo[0] = [45, 20, 0]
allRectInfo[1] = [45, 60, 0]
allRectInfo[2] = [45, 100, 0]
# [...]
```

Increment the hit counter when a hit is identified:

```py
for i in range (numRects):
      if # [...]

            # [...]

            allRectInfo[i][2] += 1
```

Define an array of colors and use the color dependent on the brick:

```py
brickcolor1 = # [...]
brickcolor2 = (255, 128, 128)
brickcolor3 = (255, 0, 0)
brickcolors = [brickcolor1, brickcolor2, brickcolor3]
```

```
currentcolor = brickcolors[allRectInfo[i][2]]
```

The brick breaks if a brick has reached the hit limit. Skip the brick in this case:

```py
for i in range (numRects):
    if allRectInfo[i][2] < 3:
        # [...]
```

All together that may look as follows:

```py
for i in range (numRects):

    if allRectInfo[i][2] < 3:

        currentcolor = brickcolors[allRectInfo[i][2]]
        fill(*currentcolor)
        rect(allRectInfo[i][0], allRectInfo[i][1], rectW, rectH)

        if allRectInfo[i][1]-25 <= y <= allRectInfo[i][1]+74 and allRectInfo[i][0]-5.5 <= x <= allRectInfo[i][0]+150:
            incry = incry * (-1)
            score = score + 1

            allRectInfo[i][2] += 1
```

Comment: can you have currentcolor in the rect function? It comes up with an error message: arg cant be coerced to float.

Comment: The only time I used rect was to draw the bricks. I think rect is a primitive and not a function?

Comment: That's where I draw the rectangle. The parameters for rect are x,y,width,height. So I took the values from the list I made to draw the rectangle.

Comment: @trashcan Now I got you. I've oversight that you are using [processing](https://processing.org/). Of course you've to set the [`fill()`](https://processing.org/reference/fill_.html) color and to draw a [`rect()`](https://processing.org/reference/rect_.html). Sew the answer.